# How can i get all pixels in a drawn rectangle client area according to the coordinates a List<Point>?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this code in a `pictureBox1` paint event:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (cloudPoints != null)
    {
        if (DrawIt)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
            int w = rect.Width;
            int h = rect.Height;
            int area = h * w;

            CloudEnteringAlert.pointtocolorinrectangle = cloudPoints;
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            CloudEnteringAlert.Paint(e.Graphics, 1, 200, bmp);
        }
    }   
}
```

`cloudPoints` is a `List<Point>` contain all pixels exist in the `pictureBox1` image.
Could be 14000 or 20.
In index 0 for example i see `x = 122 y = 34`

Now rect is a rectangle i draw using mouse move.

Then i send to the `CloudEnteringAlert` Paint method the coordinates of pixels to paint/color in yellow.
Now it will paint/color all the pixels in the `cloudPoints` List.

But i want to change it so it will paint/color only the pixels coordinates that are inside the rectangle i drawed.

So if for example the pixels in `cloudPoints` exist in the area client of the drawn rectangle send only this coordinates. Not all the coordinates in the `cloudPoints` only those that are in the drawn rectangle.

Comment: So you want to color a selection of pixels a certain color, but only within the bounds of another rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Rectangle.Contains(Point)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t27w02(v=vs.110).aspx) method. So, if you want to get the points that are within the rectangle just filter the list

```
var pointsAffected = cloudPoints.Where(pt => rect.Contains(pt))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the width and the height of your rectangle and say, the left-top corner coordinates x0,y0, so to filter the list of coordinates you can think that all coordinates x,y that are within the desired area are in following equation:

```
(x0 < x < (x0+width)) and (y0 < y < (y0+width)).
```

According to this you can filter your pixels with this restriction: Something similar to the answer form @hometoast

```
cloudPoints.Where(pt => pt.x < (x0+width) && pt.x>x0 &&pt.y>y0 && pt.y< (y0+width)))
```

For circles and other figures you can make a similar equation to filter the pixels. Example for circle is: `(x-x0)^2 + (y-y0)^2 <= r^2`